# Get The Class Name From an Object Variable

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I would like to the get the class that is being pointed to from an Object variable.

For instance, if I have an instance of a StringBuilder object that I subsequently set an Object variable to, can I somehow know that the Object variable points to a StringBuilder object?

Example:

```
StringBuilder sbText = New StringBuilder();
Object oMyObject = sbText;
// How can I determine that oMyObject points to an instance of StringBuilder object using only oMyObject
```

I have tried using `typeof(oMyObject)` or `oMyObject.GetType()` in every combination I can think of and still keep coming up with nothing more than `Object`. 
Seems like there should be a fairly straight forward way to do this and there probably is but I am not finding it.

I must disagree with the user who marked this as a duplicate question to the one they provided the link to. The title of my question may not have been as clear as it could have been (I have altered it a bit now) and the answers to both may involve the same method but the user who asked the other question was looking for a way to instantiate an object as the same type as another object. I was only looking for the way to get the name of a class when all I have is a variable of type Object. I would never have come up with the answer that Reed provided by looking at that question and I don't recall it ever coming up in a search on this site or a wider Google search.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`GetType()` should provide the proper `System.Type` of the object at runtime.

For example, this prints `"StringBuilder"`:

```
StringBuilder sbText = new StringBuilder();
Object oMyObject = sbText;

Console.WriteLine(oMyObject.GetType().Name);
```

Note that if you just want to check for a specific class type, `is` (or `as`) often works more cleanly than getting a `Type`:

```
StringBuilder sbText = new StringBuilder();
Object oMyObject = sbText;

//...

StringBuilder sb = oMyObject as StringBuilder;
if (sb != null)
{
    // oMyObject was a StringBuilder - you can use sb as needed:
    sb.AppendText("Foo");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Reed. The first example is exactly what I was looking for. I needed to get the class name (eg: StringBuilder, Widget, MyClass or whatever) without comparing it to some hard coded list of classes. That would be impossible for what I am doing. Thanks again for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you are storing the `Type` into an object.  Try this:

```
Type myType = sbText.GetType();
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I determine that oMyObject points to an instance of StringBuilder object using only oMyObject

you can do this

```
StringBuilder sbText = new StringBuilder();
Object oMyObject = sbText;
if (oMyObject is StringBuilder)
{
   StringBuilder sb = (StringBuilder)oMyObject; // safe now as you know type
   //your code
}
```

However if you need to get the type you need to use [GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) on object.

Answer (score 0):

All of these will work:

```
StringBuilder sbText = new StringBuilder();
Object oMyObject = sbText;

oMyObject is StringBuilder;
oMyObject.GetType() == typeof(StringBuilder);

StringBuilder test = oMyObject as StringBuilder;
if (test != null)
{
  //Do Work
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (oMyObject is StringBuilder) { ... }
```